# Ошибка "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type"

Tags: c#, ооп

Ошибка в функции public Matrix ARRAYxARRAY(Matrix fMatrix, Matrix sMatrix)
Как исправить?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Matrix
{
    protected int row, column;
    protected int[,] ARRAY;

    public int ROW {
        get { return row; }
        set { row = value; }
    }

    public int COLUMN {
        get { return column; }
        set { column = value; }
    }

    public Matrix() {

    }

    public Matrix(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;

        ARRAY = new int[this.COLUMN, this.ROW];
    }

    public void EnterMatrix() {
        Console.Write("enter the numbers of matrix columns: ");
        COLUMN = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("enter the numbers of matrix rows: ");
        ROW = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        ARRAY = new int[COLUMN, ROW];

        for (int col = 0; col < COLUMN; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < ROW; row++) {
                Console.Write("enter the elements of matrix cell[" + (col + 1) + ":" + (row + 1) + "]: ");
                ARRAY[col, row] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Display() {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLUMN; col++) {
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int row = 0; row < ROW; row++) {
                Console.Write("{0}\t", ARRAY[col, row]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void ARRAYxARRAY(int number, Matrix sMatrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ROW; j++) {
                ARRAY[i, j] += number * sMatrix.ARRAY[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    public Matrix ARRAYxARRAY(Matrix fMatrix, Matrix sMatrix) {
        int rows1 = fMatrix.ROW, cols1 = fMatrix.COLUMN,
            rows2 = sMatrix.ROW, cols2 = sMatrix.COLUMN;

        Matrix tMatrix = new Matrix(rows1, cols2);
        if (cols1 == rows2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols2; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < cols1; k++) {
                        tMatrix[i, j] += fMatrix[i, k] * sMatrix[k, j];
                    }
                }
            }
            return tMatrix;
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Matrixes can`t be multiplied.");
        }
        return tMatrix;
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        Console.WriteLine("Matrix has been denied.");
    }
}

class Vector : Matrix {
    public Vector() {

    }

    public Vector(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;

        ARRAY = new int[this.COLUMN, this.ROW];
    }


    ~Vector() {
        Console.WriteLine("Vector has been denied.");
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Matrix MATRIX = new Matrix();
        MATRIX.EnterMatrix();
        Console.WriteLine("The matrix is: ");
        MATRIX.Display();

        Console.Write("enter the number to multiply by: ");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        MATRIX.ARRAYxARRAY(number, MATRIX);
        MATRIX.Display();

        MATRIX.ARRAYxARRAY(MATRIX, MATRIX);
        MATRIX.Display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не умножение матриц. Вот честно. А по сути вопроса - а в чем проблема? Не работает? Не собирается? [mcve] может. И да, с точки зрения ООП и логики это ужас. Методы модифицирует то что не должны.

Comment: Покажите, как вы пытались решить вашу задачу, какие проблемы у вас с этим возникли. То, что вы привели, не содержит ваших попыток перемножения матриц, то есть бесполезно.

Comment: В общем случае одинаковые матрицы перемножить невозможно вприципе. Умножение матриц определено для матриц размерами *l x m и m x n*

Comment: "Ошибка в функции" - конкурс "Угадай ошибку!"? А, нашел!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tMatrix.ARRAY[i, j] += fMatrix.ARRAY[i, k] * sMatrix.ARRAY[k, j];
```

или

```
  tMatrix[i, j] = tMatrix[i, j] + fMatrix[i, k] * sMatrix[k, j];

public int this[int iRow, iCol]
{
  get { return ARRAY[iRow, iCol]; }
  set { ARRAY[iRow, iCol] = value; }
}
```